# I'm trying to lerp forward the player a fixed distance but it only works once. How do I allow the player to be moved more than once?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

Please check the code. Once the player moves the fixed distance once, he doesn't move again even when the space input is given. 
How Do I make it such that I can keep moving the player after the player has been moved once?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovementPC : MonoBehaviour
{

    [Header ("Move Settings")]

    private Vector3 StartingPosition, EndingPosition;
    public float moveDistance = 30f;
    public float LerpTime = 1f;
    private float CurrentLerpTime = 0;
    public bool movePressed = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartingPosition = transform.position;
        EndingPosition = transform.position + Vector3.forward * moveDistance;

    }

    void Update()
    { 

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space")) 
        {
            movePressed = true;
            Debug.Log("dash pressed");
        }



        if (movePressed == true)
        {
            CurrentLerpTime += Time.unscaledDeltaTime;

            if (CurrentLerpTime >= LerpTime)
            {
                CurrentLerpTime = LerpTime;
            }

            float LerpPercentage = CurrentLerpTime / LerpTime;
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(StartingPosition, EndingPosition, LerpPercentage);

        }

    }
```

Any Help would be appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: well once you get to endposition, nothing changes that position so it wont move again  You probably want to set the start and end positions when you detect the mouse down and when its reached the end turn movepressed to false

Comment: Thanks for the reply @BugFinder, I tried that it didn't work as intended, any more ideas?

Comment: no tbh there isnt enough detail to know what is or isnt happening

Comment: You don't reset movePressed to false.

Comment: @Kamiky i tried adding it, it didn't work as intended and started looping me back to startpos

Comment: Try replace transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(StartingPosition, EndingPosition, LerpPercentage);
to  StartingPosition = transform.position; EndingPosition = transform.position + Vector3.forward * moveDistance; transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(StartingPosition, EndingPosition, LerpPercentage);

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are not resetting the variables that control the start/end positions of the movement.  The `Start()` method is called when the object is added to the level, or Play is pressed and that is currently the only method that resets those values.  Therefore if you want those values reset you need to determine when the movement has finished, something like:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovementPC : MonoBehaviour
{

    [Header ("Move Settings")]

    private Vector3 StartingPosition, EndingPosition;
    public float moveDistance = 30f;
    public float LerpTime = 1f;
    private float CurrentLerpTime = 0;

    private void Start()
    {
        ResetPositions();
    }

    void Update()
    { 

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space")) 
        {
            CurrentLerpTime += Time.unscaledDeltaTime;

            if (CurrentLerpTime >= LerpTime)
            {
                ResetPositions();
                return;
            }

            float LerpPercentage = CurrentLerpTime / LerpTime;
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(StartingPosition, EndingPosition, LerpPercentage);

        }
    }

    void ResetPositions()
    {
        StartingPosition = transform.position;
        EndingPosition = transform.position + Vector3.forward * moveDistance;
        CurrentLerpTime = 0;
    }
```